# Location of static Variables

Tags: c++, c

Try_1:

```
int data;
int main()
{
printf("%d",data);
}
-bash-3.2$ size a.out 
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1260     504      24    1788     6fc a.out
```

Try_2:

```
int data;
static int data2;
int main()
{

printf("%d",data);
printf("%d",data2);
}
-bash-3.2$ size a.out 
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1292     504      24    1820     71c a.out
```

From the above code , it looks like file scoped static variable are stored in text section. Can some explain me this behaviour? I expected it to store in bss section.

Comment: Both `data` and `data2` are stored in the same area. Both have static storage duration. Point being the `static` keyword is redundant in this example.

Comment: Incidentally, the increase in size of the `.text` section is easy to explain here: there's twice as much code in your `main` function!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `size` tool isn't really precise enough to investigate this for you. It looks like you're on Linux, so you can try `readelf`, which is way more informative. I put this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int data;

int main (void)
{
    printf("%d",data);
    return 0;
}
```

in a file called `sections.c` then compiled it with `gcc -o sections sections.c`. Now calling `readelf -a sections >readelf.txt` gives lots of output (probably too much to paste in an answer here), but there are some interesting tidbits.

Firstly, somewhere in the symbol table you see a line like

```
    56: 080496bc     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 data
```

(In hindsight, it probably would have been better to use a name that was easier to search for than "data"). Anyway, this means that the `data` symbol has value 0x080496bc. That should correspond to the load address of the variable, so we can now go and look at the section table.

The sections in question:

```
[13] .text             PROGBITS        08048300 000300 0001a2 00  AX  0   0 16
...
[24] .data             PROGBITS        080496b0 0006b0 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
[25] .bss              NOBITS          080496b8 0006b8 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
```

The first hex column is the starting address for the section and the third is its size. In particular, `.bss` spans `[0x080496b8, 0x080496bf]`, the last four bytes of which are `data`. Tada!

Answer (score 1):

You should expect that every section has padding associated with it, which invalidates your experiment unless you declare large arrays, e.g. `int data[2048]`.